# PHP query - on 1st, 5th, 9th record add a class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im wondering if its possible with PHP to add a class to X record returned. I know I can do this with JS only I'd like it to have the class added as the records are returned.

I have the following loop in my PHP, From what I've found in google I need to add a counter to do this only I've been unsuccessful so far...

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<div class="entry span3"><span class="name">' . $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . "</span>";
        echo '<img src="' . $row["picture_1"] . '" alt="' . $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . ', text ' . $row['Date'] . ' ">';
        echo '<span class="from">seen in ' . ucwords($row["Location_County__Seen"]) . '</span><a href="/' . strtolower($row["Surname"]) . '/' . $row["ID"] . '">View Profile</a></div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In front of your while, add `$c = 1`

Before the end of your while loop, add `$c++;`

Then, modify your first line:

`echo '<div class="entry span3"><span class="name">'`

To

```
echo '<div class="entry span3';
if (($c % 4) == 1) echo ' newclassname ';
echo '"><span class="name">'
```

For the final result:

```
$c = 1;
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<div class="entry';
    if (($c % 4) == 1) echo ' newclassname ';
    echo ' span3"><span class="name">' . $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . "</span>";
    echo '<img src="' . $row["picture_1"] . '" alt="' . $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . ', text ' . $row['Date'] . ' ">';
    echo '<span class="from">seen in ' . ucwords($row["Location_County__Seen"]) . '</span><a href="/' . strtolower($row["Surname"]) . '/' . $row["ID"] . '">View Profile</a></div>';

    $c++;
}
```